# B2c accelerator hybris 1905 : install.bat -r b2c_acc_plus not working

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

I have an exception when I try to run `install.bat -r b2c_acc_plus` , can you help me to resolve it ?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.<clinit>(ReflectionCache.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:241)
    at de.hybris.installer.CmdHandler.<clinit>(CmdHandler.groovy:12)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberMetaMethod.(NumberNumberMetaMethod.java:33)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.createMetaMethodFromClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:257)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.(GroovySystem.java:36)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.(InvokerHelper.java:86)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:86)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:241)
at de.hybris.installer.CmdHandler.(CmdHandler.groovy:12)

Comment: Can you check your java version and existing receipts?

Comment: I have java 8/11/17 and the recipes are existing .

Comment: Hi @SoufyaneMechitoui please check java home it might be picking Java 17

Comment: Hi @RaushanKumar , I set it in 3 different vesion but still not working .

Comment: Hi @SoufyaneMechitoui have u tried any other recipe

Comment: Hi @RaushanKumar no , I will try

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I used to work for SAP in the product support department. I was trying to install Hybris myself recently and ran into the same problem.

The issue is with your version of Java. It must be too recent. It looks like you're using a recipe from SAP Commerce v1905 or earlier?

Try installing the SAPMachine JVM v11 from their website and set your JAVA_HOME and PATH to point to that version and try again.

You can downlaod their JVM here:
https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/

I hope this helps :)